# Cant get it to show text from an array to the html

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

My problem is that I can't get Javascript to change the text in an HTML `p` tag.

I got this HTML `button` with `id="knap"` and I got this `p` tag with `id="answer"`. I want that if user clicks on the button, then the text in "answer" will change.

In the Javascript code, I got an array carrying all the answers:

I got the following code – never tried Javascript, but have programmed in other languages –:

(Im using an external JS document)

```
var answer = [
    "answer1",
    "answer2",
    "answer3",
    "answer4"
];

document.getElementById("knap").onclick = function() {
    var panel = document.getElementById("answer");
    panel.innerHTML = answer[1];
}
```

This is my html button:

```
<a class="button" href="#">
<div id="knap">
<h1>Something</h1>
</div>
</a>
```

How to fix it?

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/84vJg/

Comment: Can you show your HTML code?

Comment: When did you assign the `onclick` to your button? Before or after the button is rendered on the page?

Comment: Do you know that your onClick function is being called? put alert("TEST") inside that onClick at its first and last line. and then tell us when you see that alert message?

Comment: He is right. It is not working for me too!! http://jsfiddle.net/84vJg/

Comment: I have added alert("test");
At the beginning of onclick = function(){
alert("test");
}

Comment: With your previous code you just needed to add `()` around `window.onload = init;` ---> `window.onload = init();`

Comment: @^ No. thats wrong. It will execute the function and assign the result(if any) to the window.onload attribute.

Comment: why does this work then? http://jsfiddle.net/84vJg/1/

Comment: Check luiso1979 answer for details

Comment: @Scott maybe jsFiddle handles it in a special way, since it is already loaded and we hit just "Run"

Comment: Testing in jsfiddle isn't exactly the same as testing on the same page that has the problem.

Comment: Yes. Just now i verified in local. The calling braces - () should not be included as i said before. Its just that, JsFiddle plays smart there in the above example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at what i did [here](http://jsfiddle.net/luiso1979/DY77F/), it works.

I just used this html, and as you would see I used your JS code.

```
<a id="knap" href="#">KNAP</a>

<p id="answer"></p>
```

I think your problem is related with the way a web page is loaded.

The JS code is loaded asynchronously, so it may happen the your DOM isn't loaded yet when the JS is executed. To ensure your DOM is loaded, you could use several mechanisms

1. Use the onReady method of jQuery
2. window.onload = myOnloadFunc
3. And putting your JS at the bottom, even if this is not a guarantee.

Tell me if you are still having problems,

Regards,

Comment: Just had to call script in html doc, and say window.onload = function
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript looks fine, unless you're running it before your HTML has been parsed, i.e. `document.getElementById("knap")` returns null/undefined.

Are you including your HTML before or after your SCRIPT?  Put your script after your HTML and it should work.

Comment: Im using an external js document. Does that change anything?

Comment: @McBoman, there's no difference in parsing between `<SCRIPT>...</SCRIPT>` and `<SCRIPT SRC="..."></SCRIPT>` in that respect.  The browser will stop parsing the HTML to execute the script.